# How to write to channel 3?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

In PHP, we can write to stdout (channel 1) via `echo` or `fwrite(STDOUT, "hello")` and stderr (channel 2) via `fwrite(STDERR, "error!")`.

How can I write to channels 3-255?

Comment: The reason for the DV's (I know, I just lived through it with another self-answered question) is that the answer might be perceived as too broad.

Comment: @JayBlanchard How can this be too broad? There's a single definitive answer.

Comment: That's what I thought too, when I wrote my latest self-answered question. I got hammered for it on Meta and I am still finding ways to improve the question. One of the posters there stated that there were 2 contradictory answers, making it too broad. Another stated a once sentence question without much context signaled it was too broad. Yet another stated it was too broad because an edit audit was failed more than once for the question. And I meant "question", not "answer" in my comment above.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Hrm.. I don't mind so much when I ask a poorly worded question, but it's pretty annoying when you think you've covered your bases.

Comment: I totally agree @mpen. I was finally able to edit and get it to a point where it was re-opened (closed in spite of the original question being heavily upvoted, along with the answer).

Answer (score 4):

You can write to an arbitrary channel (file descriptor) like so:

```
$fp = fopen('php://fd/3','w');
fwrite($fp, "hello");
```

This is documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).